# how to plot the projection of a vector?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have made the following program for calculating the vector projection:

```
a=[6 7]
b=[1 4]
p=(dot(a,b)/(b*b'))*b
```

the result of p is [2 8] that is the projection of a on b.

I read that for plotting a vector in Matlab I should choose some origin points, so I have added those to the vectors and form a set of matrices with them like this:

```
x=[0 0; 6 7]
y=[0 0; 1 4]
z=[0 0; 2 8]
plot3(x,y,z)
grid;
```

but I cannot get to visualize the projection, what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You define `a` and `b`,  compute `p`,  and then you plot something else. Your question is very unclear. Please explain how `x`, `y` , `z` are related to `a`, `b`

Comment: thank you @LuisMendo, it was a typo I have corrected the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `quiver` for 2D vector plotting or `quiver3` for 3D plotting.

```
a = [6 7];
b = [1 4];
p = (dot(a,b)/dot(b,b))*b;

figure;
quiver(0,0,a(1), a(2));
hold on;
quiver(0,0,b(1), b(2));
quiver(0,0,p(1), p(2));
```

Comment: it should be the dot product of b and not to use norm(x)

Comment: still, it only plots a line; I would like to see the three vectors separated

Comment: then you have to use `hold on`